# Invoke-webrequest image size

Tags: powershell

The Script below loops through each URL and invokes a web request and downloads images from it. The problem that i am facing is the images are by default getting downloaded in 320X240; where as on the actual site the image when opened in a new tab and right click downloaded, gives me a 960X720 pix file, which is what I am after.

**Here is the script.**

```
$url = get-content “urls.txt”
$j = $url.count
for ($i= 0 ; $i -le $j ; $i++)
{
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url[$i]
ForEach ($Image in $WebResponse.Images)
{
$FileName = Split-Path $Image.src -Leaf
$d =  Invoke-WebRequest $Image.src
}
}
```

Here are the links just a couple of them:
http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2013/08/part-1-introduction-to-html; 
 http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2013/08/part-2-reading-writing-to-console.html

Answer (score 0):

Compare the `$Image.src` with the mentionend 'new tab', are these urls the same?

Probably you need to use `$WebResponse.Links` (which end with *.jpg) and not `$WebResponse.Images`.